# thmtools and mdframed (vertical space)

Tags: vertical-alignment, mdframed, thmtools

I dont know why I dont get the two examples closer together.
How can I achieve a spacing of `0mm` between the two Examples?

```
    %!TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode


% DEFINITIONS ===================================================
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    a4paper,
    twoside,
    headings=normal,
    titlepage=true
]{scrreprt}


\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


% Math
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
% Emphasize
\usepackage[]{empheq}
% \RequirePackage[hyperref,thref,amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage{lipsum}



\declaretheoremstyle[%
        headfont=\bfseries, %
        notebraces={(}{)},%
        bodyfont=\normalfont,%
        notefont=\itshape,%
        headpunct={:},%
        postheadspace=\newline,%
        postheadhook={}, %{\textcolor{red}{\rule[.6ex]{\linewidth}{0.4pt}}\\},%
        spacebelow=0\parsep,%
        spaceabove=0\parsep,
        mdframed={%
          linecolor=black,%
          leftline=false,%
          rightline=false,%
          topline=true,%
          bottomline=true,%
          middlelinewidth=1pt,%
          innertopmargin=0.0\baselineskip,%
          innerbottommargin=0.0\baselineskip,%
          innerleftmargin=0pt,%
          innerrightmargin=0pt,%
          skipbelow=0pt,%
          skipabove=0pt%
        }%%
]{myFramedDefinitionStyle}%

\declaretheorem[
    style=myFramedDefinitionStyle,
    name=Definition,
    numberwithin=chapter
]{definition1}

% Basic Command
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{definition} { o o }
     {%
      \IfNoValueTF{#1} {\begin{definition1}}{ \begin{definition1}[#1] }%                                  
      \IfNoValueTF{#2} {}{\label{#2}}%
     }%
     {%
      \end{definition1}%
     }%
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[asd]
asdasd
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}[asd]
asdasd
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Here the image:
[image]